# How to reload database data in junit test fastly?

Tags: java, spring, junit, hsqldb

I develop an application in Java with Spring and Hibernate. And now I am looking for a solution for fast reloading data between tests. The tests require a lot of data, which are generated and persisted through services. As a db I use hsqldb in memory. Data generating process takes about 30 seconds, so it is too long to simply run it before each test.

So I was wondering if it is good idea and if it is possible with hsqldb to run data loader once at the begining of test case or suite, then create a dump and restore it before each test? I can't find how to create dump in hsqldb, especially if it is in memory db.

I appreaciate all yours help.

EDIT: I have to use database. Let's consider that they re integration tests.

Comment: Have you considered mocking the data you want to access from within your test? This might be a lot faster...

Comment: +1 for the comment, the database should be mocked when writing unit test for controller or models .. I believe you should only interact with actual data set when writing test for your DAO layer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html) to load and clean the database before and after each test but I don't think that will improve your performance.

Instead, I would ask why you need so much data for a unit test?  30 seconds isn't too bad for an integration test that actually hits a database, but I think you should strive to have unit tests that don't hit the database at all and instead use mock objects to simulate interacting with your services.  Then you can have a *few* integration tests that actually use a database but those tests won't have to cover all scenarios since your faster unit tests should do that already.

Comment: yep. Creating whole database is clearly overhead, you should use mock data. If you need to use the in-memory DB nevertheless, possibility might be to restore only records you have modified by test(eg. cache records you plan to modify in test and restore their original state after the test is finished)

Comment: I was using dbUnit but now I change the way and use test data builders pattern. I don't want to have static test data anymore. And the tests are integration tests. No all of my tests will use this db reloading mechanism.

Comment: @Jan Hruby - I'd prefer option with restoring starting version of db instead of performing opposite actions to that performed in test. Is it possible?

Comment: you could store your transaction to a stack and after test just perform rollback on each one of them. I do not know, if it is possible automatically using some annotation/property

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HSQLDB `file:` database with the default MEMORY tables.

After generating the dataset, add the property `files_readonly=true` to the database.properties file. You then run the tests with this database. This ensures your tests run and modify the data the same way as a `mem:` database, but the changes made by the tests are not persisted when the test process ends. The original data is loaded in a few seconds in the fastest possible way.

Answer (score 0):

try using this annotation in your test class

`@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="nameOfYourTransactionManager", defaultRollback=true)`

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332213/hsqldb-spring-unit-tests-not-rolling-back)